# Can't "npm install" when downloading new code on git

Tags: node.js, npm

I download my code on gitlab and use "npm install" to create "node-modules" but failed. Please help me

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vue-material-admin@1.0.3
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^7.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@">= 1.6.0 < 7.0.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"~4.5.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-26T17_56_58_931Z-debug.log
```

Help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! git dep preparation failed when trying to install package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434750/npm-err-git-dep-preparation-failed-when-trying-to-install-package-json)

Comment: Does your organization use their own repository?  Or is the package.json referencing internal packages?  That error is an error trying to authenticate to a Sonatype package repo, not the usual npmjs one

Comment: Did you figure it out and can you post your gitlab-ci.yml ?