# When I intstall npm in Laravel 9 got strange errors

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install

I try to intstall npm in Laravel 9 site and got strange errors :

```
npm install
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: bootstrap-switch@3.3.4
npm WARN Found: bootstrap@4.6.2
npm WARN node_modules/bootstrap
npm WARN   dev bootstrap@"^4.6.0" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (admin-lte, bootstrap-colorpicker, tempusdominus-bootstrap-4)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer bootstrap@"^3.1.1" from bootstrap-switch@3.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/bootstrap-switch
npm WARN   bootstrap-switch@"3.3.4" from admin-lte@3.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/admin-lte
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: bootstrap@3.4.1
npm WARN node_modules/bootstrap
npm WARN   peer bootstrap@"^3.1.1" from bootstrap-switch@3.3.4
npm WARN   node_modules/bootstrap-switch
npm WARN     bootstrap-switch@"3.3.4" from admin-lte@3.2.0
npm WARN     node_modules/admin-lte
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated flag-icon-css@4.1.7: The project has been renamed to flag-icons
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.15.0 -> 8.19.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.19.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.19.1 to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/home/hoster/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile vue-next: No matching version found for vue-next@3.2.37.
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/lib/index.js:209:23)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:125:22)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:784:9)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile  Could not fetch metadata for vue-next@3.2.37 vue-next: No matching version found for vue-next@3.2.37.
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/lib/index.js:209:23)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:125:22)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:784:9) {
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   code: 'ETARGET',
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   type: 'version',
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   wanted: '3.2.37',
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   versions: [ '0.0.1' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   distTags: { latest: '0.0.1' },
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   defaultTag: 'latest'
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile }
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-test-utils - Not found
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:93:15
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:784:9)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile  Could not fetch metadata for vue-next-test-utils@2.0.0-rc.16 HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-test-utils - Not found
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:93:15
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:784:9) {
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   headers: [Object: null prototype] {
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     date: [ 'Mon, 12 Sep 2022 12:27:07 GMT' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-length': [ '21' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'cf-ray': [ '7498a2ad69ce9bb0-FRA' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     vary: [ 'Accept-Encoding' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     server: [ 'cloudflare' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'x-fetch-attempts': [ '1' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'x-local-cache-status': [ 'skip' ]
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   },
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   statusCode: 404,
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   code: 'E404',
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   method: 'GET',
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   uri: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-test-utils',
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   body: { error: 'Not found' },
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   pkgid: 'vue-next-test-utils@2.0.0-rc.16'
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile }
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-rollup-plugin-vue - Not found
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:93:15
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:784:9)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile  Could not fetch metadata for vue-next-rollup-plugin-vue@6.0.0 HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-rollup-plugin-vue - Not found
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:93:15
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:784:9) {
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   headers: [Object: null prototype] {
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     date: [ 'Mon, 12 Sep 2022 12:27:07 GMT' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-length': [ '21' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'cf-ray': [ '7498a2adadf0695e-FRA' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     vary: [ 'Accept-Encoding' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     server: [ 'cloudflare' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'x-fetch-attempts': [ '1' ],
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'x-local-cache-status': [ 'skip' ]
npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   },


                                        ...
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     /home/hoster/.npm/_logs/2022-09-12T12_26_51_309Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hoster/.npm/_logs/2022-09-12T12_25_43_401Z-debug-0.log
```

I see messages

```
7507 error npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
```

and

```
7507 error npm WARN old lockfile vue-next: No matching version found for vue-next@3.2.37.
7507 error npm WARN old lockfile     at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/lib/index.js:209:23)
```

Before running install command I removed all lock files in root of my project.

```
hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ node -v
v16.17.0
hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ npm -v
8.15.0
hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ uname -a
Linux hoster-os 5.15.0-41-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 13:27:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In package.json I have :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.10.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.5.1",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.6",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
        "admin-lte": "^3.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.11.7",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "overlayscrollbars": "^1.13.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "pusher-js": "^7.1.0-beta",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.49.8",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.30",
        "vue-loader": "^16.1.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^32.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^2.0.1",
        "@vueform/multiselect": "github:vueform/multiselect",
        "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^3.1.1",
        "@vueup/vue-quill": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
        "codemirror": "^6.0.1",
        "mitt": "^3.0.0",
        "quill-better-table": "^1.2.10",
        "quill-blot-formatter": "^1.0.5",
        "sanitize-html": "^2.7.0",
        "vue-color-kit": "^1.0.5",
        "vue-final-modal": "^3.4.3",
        "vue-upload-component": "^3.1.2",
        "vue3-colorpicker": "^2.0.4",
        "vuejs-paginate-next": "^1.0.2"
    }
}
```

Why I got this error and how it could be fixed ?

**UPDATED INFO:**

I try to follow steps in the link, but I still errors :

1. I removed files composer.lock and package-lock.json from root of the app
   I manually deleted subdirectories node_modules and vendor
2. I run command

   composer install

with success

3. I run command under sudo(otherwise I got access error):
   sudo npm install -g npm@8.19.1 to update

with success , but some warnings :

```
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.2.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.3.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.

changed 657 packages, and audited 853 packages in 2m

19 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

53 vulnerabilities (7 low, 3 moderate, 41 high, 2 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

4. and check npm version :

   $ npm -v
   8.19.1
5. clear cache :

   npm cache clean --force
   npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
6. But running npm install I got error again :

```
    hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ npm install
    npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
    npm WARN While resolving: bootstrap-switch@3.3.4
    npm WARN Found: bootstrap@4.6.2
    npm WARN node_modules/bootstrap
    npm WARN   dev bootstrap@"^4.6.0" from the root project
    npm WARN   3 more (admin-lte, bootstrap-colorpicker, tempusdominus-bootstrap-4)
    npm WARN
    npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
    npm WARN peer bootstrap@"^3.1.1" from bootstrap-switch@3.3.4
    npm WARN node_modules/bootstrap-switch
    npm WARN   bootstrap-switch@"3.3.4" from admin-lte@3.2.0
    npm WARN   node_modules/admin-lte
    npm WARN
    npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: bootstrap@3.4.1
    npm WARN node_modules/bootstrap
    npm WARN   peer bootstrap@"^3.1.1" from bootstrap-switch@3.3.4
    npm WARN   node_modules/bootstrap-switch
    npm WARN     bootstrap-switch@"3.3.4" from admin-lte@3.2.0
    npm WARN     node_modules/admin-lte
    npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
    npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
    npm WARN deprecated flag-icon-css@4.1.7: The project has been renamed to flag-icons
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
    npm ERR! command /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/home/hoster/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
    npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile vue-next: No matching version found for vue-next@3.2.37.
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/lib/index.js:209:23)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:125:22)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:738:24)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile  Could not fetch metadata for vue-next@3.2.37 vue-next: No matching version found for vue-next@3.2.37.
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/lib/index.js:209:23)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:125:22)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:738:24) {
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   code: 'ETARGET',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   type: 'version',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   wanted: '3.2.37',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   versions: [ '0.0.1' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   distTags: { latest: '0.0.1' },
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   defaultTag: 'latest'
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile }
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-rollup-plugin-vue - Not found
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:738:24)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile  Could not fetch metadata for vue-next-rollup-plugin-vue@6.0.0 HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-rollup-plugin-vue - Not found
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-length': [ '21' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'cf-ray': [ '74c9ec85b945bbb0-FRA' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     vary: [ 'Accept-Encoding' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     server: [ 'cloudflare' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'x-fetch-attempts': [ '1' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'x-local-cache-status': [ 'skip' ]
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   },
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   statusCode: 404,
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   code: 'E404',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   method: 'GET',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   uri: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-rollup-plugin-vue',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   body: { error: 'Not found' },
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   pkgid: 'vue-next-rollup-plugin-vue@6.0.0'
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile }
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-prev - Not found
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:738:24)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile  Could not fetch metadata for vue-prev@2.7.8 HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-prev - Not found
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:738:24) {
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   headers: [Object: null prototype] {
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     date: [ 'Sun, 18 Sep 2022 12:00:55 GMT' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-length': [ '21' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'cf-ray': [ '74c9ec86fbe39054-FRA' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     vary: [ 'Accept-Encoding' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     server: [ 'cloudflare' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'x-fetch-attempts': [ '1' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'x-local-cache-status': [ 'skip' ]
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   },
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   statusCode: 404,
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   code: 'E404',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   method: 'GET',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   uri: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-prev',
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   body: { error: 'Not found' },
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   pkgid: 'vue-prev@2.7.8'
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile }
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-jest - Not found
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:738:24)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile  Could not fetch metadata for vue-next-jest@27.0.0 HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-next-jest - Not found
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     at async Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:738:24) {
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile   headers: [Object: null prototype] {
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     date: [ 'Sun, 18 Sep 2022 12:00:55 GMT' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'content-length': [ '21' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     'cf-ray': [ '74c9ec8859a05c56-FRA' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     vary: [ 'Accept-Encoding' ],
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile     server: [ 'cloudflare' ],
    ...
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/hoster/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonesvo8QA/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-41-generic
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/hoster/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonesvo8QA/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/hoster/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonesvo8QA/node_modules/node-sass
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
    npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR! npm ERR!     /home/hoster/.npm/_logs/2022-09-18T12_00_30_495Z-debug-0.log
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/hoster/.npm/_logs/2022-09-18T11_58_50_566Z-debug-0.log

7) Again I pay attention at lines in error :


    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile
    npm ERR! npm WARN old lockfile vue-next: No matching version found for vue-next@3.2.37.
```

I have deleted package-lock.json file before I run npm install ?

?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to install all the `dependencies` one by one and see if it works.

Comment: Not sure that I have understood you. Do you mean manually to remove all custom packages from package.json at first ?

Comment: with the newer version of npm execute, npm install --package-lock-only This will regenerate the packagelock.json

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: I tried with node version: 14.15.1
and npm v6.14.8.
and installed it perfectly. 

so, if you want to run on updated versions, then you should update your packages.  @PetroGromovo

Comment: @PetroGromovo yes.

Comment: I wrote above : hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ node -v
v16.17.0
hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ npm -v
8.15.0

Comment: Can it be that my version is too high?

Comment: I managed to run command 
 npm install --package-lock-only
with success

But next I got :

$ npm run watch-poll 
 
> watch-poll 
> mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000 
 
sh: 1: mix: not found
 

Sorry, I am confused at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Node v14`, I had the same issue with `Node v16` because that project had some old dependencies, which were deprecated and not workable with the latest version of `Node`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `package-lock.json` is not valid.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434750/npm-err-git-dep-preparation-failed-when-trying-to-install-package-json):

The first thing you want to do is update your NPM:

```
npm install -g npm@8.19.1 to update
```

After that, delete your `package-lock.json` & `node_modules` folder.

Next clear your NPM cache using

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and re-install your dependencies with

```
npm install
```

You should be able to run `npm run dev`.

Comment: and delete the .lock file just in case

Comment: Please look UPDATED INFO:

Answer (score 1):

This error means, some package looks for some version of a dependency, but this dependency has been declared with a different version requested by earlier package, it prevents a lot of pitfalls, such as some package use something of overrided version of dependency and deal with deprecations or major incompatibilities. So Npm is protecting you from a painful work.

But you can instruct npm installs everything whatever happens. very not recommended:

```
npm install --force
```

it will installs all but there no warranties about all dependencies have correct versions of their dependencies.